# How do I search for emails having attachments in Outlook?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

How can I use `has:attachment`, `from:abc@abc.com` etc in Outlook?

[image]

This is how the search bar looks like. I am not able to edit the `From`, `Body` etc fields. How can I do this in Outlook 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> from:*emailAddress* hasattachments:true

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/find-emails-with-attachments-with-outlook-2007s-instant-search/)